# Python how to create fraction without using modules

Tags: fractions

I want to define a function named 'fraction' that given two integer 'numerator,denominator' as arguments and then use return to return them in (numerator/denominator) and the resulting fraction reduced in correct form without using (fraction import fraction,math.inf,gcd and other modules)

the problem is that I want to use range from 2 - numerator+1 and denominator+1
but it won't work so I put 100

example

fraction(9,24)

> 3/8

fraction(16,-48)

> -1/3

```html
def fraction( numerator, denominator):  
    for divisor in range(2,100):
        if (numerator % divisor == 0 and denominator % divisor == 0):
            return(fraction(numerator / divisor, denominator / divisor))
    return('{}/{}'.format(numerator, denominator))
```